# S3 PutObject 403 permission denied errors

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket for which I am trying to upload objects into from a C# SDK application (.Net 4.6.1).

This is my public access block:

```
PublicAccessBlockConfiguration = new PublicAccessBlockConfiguration()
    {
        IgnorePublicAcls = false,
        RestrictPublicBuckets = false,
        BlockPublicPolicy = false,
        BlockPublicAcls = false
    }
```

The bucket has this policy applied to it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [

        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action":[
            "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket2023/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket2023"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Calling code:

```
var request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
    BucketName = @"testbucket2023/testtag",
    Key = @"i/file.jpg",
    ContentType = contentType,
    InputStream = fileData,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
};
var response = S3Client.PutObject(request);
```

When I call PutObject, I get this error:

> {"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
> provided. Check your key and signing method."}
>
> Inner exception:
>
> {"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}

What else do I need to set to make this work? I will lock down the bucket to a specific principal once it is working.

Comment: **Warning:** You have granted the entire world permission to do _anything_ to your bucket, including uploading files, listing objects, deleting objects and even deleting the bucket itself! Instead of granting permissions via a Bucket Policy, you should grant permissions on the IAM User or IAM Role that is being used when making the `PutObject` request. If you want to make the uploaded objects publicly accessible, then using `PublicRead` is sufficient. Alternatively, you can grant `s3:GetObject` in a Bucket Policy (but _never_ grant `s3:*`).

Comment: How are you providing credentials to this code? Have you saved an Access Key and Secret Key in a configuration file via `aws configure`, or are you running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned IAM Role? The error suggests that something is wrong with the credentials you are using.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for the feedback. The bucket is temporary and is removed right after the Put call shown in my question. I'll lock down to a specific Principal once I get past this 403 issue.

Comment: When the code is running locally it is using credentials from the credentials file. The credentials are working because I am able to make other S3 calls just fine (like creating and removing the bucket). Once the code is deployed, it will use an instance profile instead of local credentials.

Comment: As an update, AWS support suggested that this is sigv4 related and maybe the headers. From AWS: Ensure that the necessary headers are set in your .Net application when making the PutObject request. This includes specifying the appropriate authentication mechanism, such as AWS Signature Version 4, and setting the required headers, such as x-amz-content-sha256. Looking via Fiddler, I do see the headers being passed to S3.

Comment: If you look at the bucket in the S3 management console, is it showing all of the **S3 Block Public Access** options as OFF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a result of the AWS SDK being very out of date. Specifically, how they handle TLS has changed significantly. Simply upgrading to the latest fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `ContentType` property is used by AWS SDK to calculate the signature. You can consider removing the property and let the SDK compute it for you to get rid of the issue. Another approach you could try is to check if the value you were passing to this property matches the content of the file you were trying to upload.

Comment: Removing the content type had no affect on the error. In my example above, I have hard coded it for a jpg. The real code has more intelligence to properly select the content type. Thanks!

Comment: Is your challenge fixed now @rboarman

Comment: The problem is still happening

Comment: @rboarman, can you share how are you loading the file data?